# PHP serve pdf download with #[destination tag]

Tags: php, pdf

Our web application is serving download links for .pdf files on a network drive opening at specific points using .pdf#[destination] in the url.

Until now this has been working fine - but in a new project we can not guarantee that the clients has user rights to the network drive.

Therefor the approach might be php serving the download with some kind of:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');

readfile('///share/folder/original.pdf');
?>
```

But how do we add the #[destination tag] for such a download - and is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up doing it like this.

The webserver needs to run as a user with read rights on the network share.

The url can look like this using the GET function `openfilefromshare.php?filepath=//192.168.x.x/share/this.pdf&#page=xxxx`

```
$fullPath = $_GET['filepath'];

if ($fd = fopen ($fullPath, "r")) {
$fsize = filesize($fullPath);
$path_parts = pathinfo($fullPath);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: inline;filename=\"".$path_parts["basename"]."\"");
header("Content-length: $fsize");
header("Cache-control: private");
while(!feof($fd)) {
    $buffer = fread($fd, 2048);
    echo $buffer;
   }
}
echo $fsize;
fclose ($fd);
```